# How to override server certificate validation when using FtpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, ftps

[`HttpWebRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLjo3hmMvSAhUJkJQKHSPtCGcQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.net.httpwebrequest.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNET-TfX7goWOOmhV-iWVFNQiy75BQ) allows you to override the logic for server certificate validation when using HTTPS.

There is no equivalent property on [`FtpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

How can I override server certificate validation when using `FtpWebRequest`?

I am aware of [`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx), but am looking for a solution that will only affect the current `FtpWebRequest` object.

Comment: Here contains one method for only affecting the current request. https://forums.asp.net/t/1455005.aspx?Accept+all+certificates+using+FTP+SSL+

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath While the code you linked to immediately reverts the `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` after use, it will still affect other concurrent requests, even ones made via other instances of `FtpWebRequest`.